# How do i change the css code below with java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to put below code by JavaScript formate in a html file . codes---

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    .ow_miniic_comment.newsfeed_comment_btn,
    .ow_miniic_like.newsfeed_like_btn,
    div.ow_dnd_widget,
    .ow_newsfeed_avatar,
    .ow_bl.ow_box_toolbar li,
    .ow_newsfeed_body,
    .ow_ipc_info {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .ow_miniic_comment.newsfeed_comment_btn.already-visible,
    .ow_miniic_like.newsfeed_like_btn.already-visible,
    div.ow_dnd_widget.already-visible,
    .ow_newsfeed_avatar.already-visible,
    .ow_bl.ow_box_toolbar li.already-visible,
    .ow_newsfeed_body.already-visible,
    .ow_ipc_info.already-visible {
        animation: none;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .ow_miniic_comment.newsfeed_comment_btn.animation_start {
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
        -moz-animation-name: zoomIn;
        -o-animation-name: zoomIn;
        -ms-animation-name: zoomIn;
        animation-name: zoomIn;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
        -moz-animation-duration: 0.3s;
        -o-animation-duration: 0.3s;
        -ms-animation-duration: 0.3s;
        animation-duration: 0.3s;
    }
}
```

want to put above code in a html file with JavaScript formate .

and is there any possibilities to compress the code to load website faster.

Comment: First of all. Why do you want to load it with javascript?

Comment: _is there any possibilities to compress the code to load website faster._ don't write it on page itself instead use external stylesheets.

Comment: because i want to some rules in JavaScript

Comment: As previously stated, scripting the styles onto your markup (HTML) would be like walking on your hands, sure it's possible with a lot of effort, but there's no point. As for compression of a stylesheet, you should minify it. Go here: http://cssminifier.com/

Comment: @AzaharUddinAhmed so you want a function that writes styles into a style tag? (e.g. `<style>....</style>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include jquery and then  put this code

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
     var style =  document.createElement('style');
     var css = "@media (min-width: 1100px) {"+
                 ".ow_miniic_comment.newsfeed_comment_btn,"+
                 ".ow_miniic_like.newsfeed_like_btn,"+
                 "div.ow_dnd_widget,"+
                 ".ow_newsfeed_avatar,"+
                 ".ow_bl.ow_box_toolbar li,"+
                 ".ow_newsfeed_body,"+
                 ".ow_ipc_info {"+
                   "visibility: hidden;"+
                 "}"+
                 ".ow_miniic_comment.newsfeed_comment_btn.already-visible,"+
                 ".ow_miniic_like.newsfeed_like_btn.already-visible,"+
                 "div.ow_dnd_widget.already-visible,"+
                 ".ow_newsfeed_avatar.already-visible,"+
                 ".ow_bl.ow_box_toolbar li.already-visible,"+
                 ".ow_newsfeed_body.already-visible,"+
                 ".ow_ipc_info.already-visible {"+
                   "animation: none;"+
                    "visibility: visible;"+
                 "}"+
                 ".ow_miniic_comment.newsfeed_comment_btn.animation_start       {"+
                 "visibility: visible;"+
                 "-webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;"+
                 "-moz-animation-name: zoomIn;"+
                 "-o-animation-name: zoomIn;"+
                 "-ms-animation-name: zoomIn;"+
                 "animation-name: zoomIn;"+
                 "-webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;"+
                 "-moz-animation-duration: 0.3s;"+
                 "-o-animation-duration: 0.3s;"+
                 "-ms-animation-duration: 0.3s;"+
                 "animation-duration: 0.3s;"+
               "}"+ 
             "}";


    style.innerHTML = css;
    $('body').prepend(style);
  });
```

Comment: It might be better if you use: `$('head').append(style);`